# Adapter won't update

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display some items on a recycleView inside a fragment. The items come from another fragment. I first create the recycleView with a empty arrayList but then when a button is pressed, data is sent through interface and a method populates the ArrayList. I have debugged this the whole day and is working perfect, when I hit the button it logs the size of the ArrayList has gone up to one.

I was reading that I have to notify my adapter when the list changes, so I tried using notifyDataSetChange(), notifyItemInserted(dataReceived.size() -1) but neither seem to work out. whenever I check adapter.getItemCount() it throws me 0, even though the arraylist says throws 1.

here's my code inside the fragment Receiving the data:

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
public ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> dataReceived;


public MyFavoriteAdapter adapter;
public FavoriteFragment() {

}

public void setDataReceived(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> dataReceived){
    this.dataReceived = dataReceived;
    Log.d("INTERFACE", "Data received by the FavoriteFragment!!!!" + " " + this.dataReceived.get(0).getCardName());
    for(int i = 0; i < dataReceived.size(); i++) {
        //THIS LINE RETURNS A 1
        Log.d("INTERFACE", "Items inside the dataReceived: " + dataReceived.size());
        //NEITHER WORKED
        //adapter.notifyItemInserted(dataReceived.size() -1);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //THIS LINE WILL KEEP ON RETURNING 0
        Log.d("INTERFACE", "Items inside the list inside the adapter: " + adapter.getItemCount());
    }
}

public static FavoriteFragment newInstance() {
    FavoriteFragment fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    dataReceived = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MyFavoriteAdapter(dataReceived);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite, container, false);

    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager myLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    myLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    if (myRecyclerView != null) {
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager);
    return view;
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

this is the adapter:

```
public class MyFavoriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{
private ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> list = new ArrayList<RecycleViewItem>();

InterfaceListItemClickListener sender = null;


public MyFavoriteAdapter(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_item_favorite, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view, sender);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(list.size() >= 1) {
        holder.favoriteImageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageResourceID());
        holder.favoriteTextView.setText(list.get(position).getCardName());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adapter has a private variable `list`, and this must be modified for `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to have any effect.

Here is your method:

```
public void setDataReceived(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> dataReceived){
    this.dataReceived = dataReceived;
    ...
}
```

Assigning the parameter `dataReceived` to your fragment's `this.dataReceived` doesn't affect your adapter's `list` in any way. Rather, you could do something like this instead:

```
public void setDataReceived(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> dataReceived){
    adapter.list.addAll(dataReceived);
    ...
}
```

You may have to make your adapter's `list` variable public, or expose it via a getter:

```
public ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> getList() {
    return list
}
```

Or even add a method that can add items to it:

```
public void addAll(ArrayList<RecycleViewItem> items) {
    list.addAll(items);
}
```

Comment: this worked thanks! I didn't really know about those add methods. The app it's still not doing what I want but at least this was fixed! I'll accept your answer when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

public void setDataReceived(ArrayList dataReceived){
    this.dataReceived.addAll(dataReceived);
    ....
}
Do not recreate list